# Xcode & Cocos2d: How Can I Set An int Property of a Scene I'm Creating?

Tags: ios, xcode, parameters, cocos2d-iphone, encapsulation

in my mainMenu.h/m I have a method that loads up the first scene of my game.

```
- (void)loadAgainstTheClockMode:(id)sender
{
    CCScene *scene = [HelloWorldLayer scene];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionZoomFlipX transitionWithDuration:0.2 scene:scene]];
}
```

As you can see I instantiate the HelloWorldLayer scene, then switch to it.

I'd like to be able to hand over an integer value to the HelloWorldLayer that will later tell it which level file to load up to save me having to repeat all the code for each level if the game.

In my HelloWorldLayer, I have set a property that i thought I'd be able to access when defining the scene...

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer

+(CCScene *)scene;
@property int levelToLoadUp;
@end
```

I was hoping to be able to do this when creating the scene...

```
- (void)loadAgainstTheClockMode:(id)sender
{
    CCScene *scene = [HelloWorldLayer scene];
    levelToLoadUp = 1;
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionZoomFlipX transitionWithDuration:0.2 scene:scene]];
}
```

Could someone please help me achieve this?  Thanks...!

Answer (score 0):

you could add a scene constructor like so :

in .h

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer {
    int _levelToLoad;
}

+(CCScene *)sceneAtLevel:(int) levelToLoad;

@end
```

in .m

```
+(CCScene*) sceneAtLevel:(int) levelToLoad {
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [[[HelloWorldLayer alloc] init ] autorelease ];
    layer->_levelToLoad = levelToLoad;

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild:layer];

    return scene;
}

// override onEnter

-(void) onEnter {

    [super onEnter];   // dont forget this when overriding any onSomething of cocos2d
    [self loadScene];
}

-(void) loadScene {
    // you can use the iVar _levelToLoad and do your 'load' thing 
    // as function of the level
}

// ps : written for MRC, if you use ARC change the memory stuff.
// pps : not tested, but should be close.
```

Comment: I just tried doing this suggested answer, however the line where the int is being set to the layer is called 'after' the init method is running within the helloworldlayer, which is where the int needs to be used. therefore the int is 0, and now giving me the result I needed. This has gotten my closer though :)

Comment: probably because you put your scene load (i think) in init. I suggested to pull it out of init, and put it in the onEnter method.